# HTTP Status 404 - spring mvc java web

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am studying the Spring Framework. I got an error while following a video tutorial. I can't figure out what's wrong. I am using Maven 3.5.0 and runs it in Tomcat 7. I am using `GET` as the request method.

web.xml

```
    <!-- webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml -->
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        version="3.0">

        <display-name>To do List</display-name>

        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>login.do</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>

         <servlet>
                <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>
                    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
                </servlet-class>
                <init-param>
                    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                    <param-value>/WEB-INF/todo-servlet.xml</param-value>
                </init-param>
                <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
            </servlet>

            <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/spring-mvc/*</url-pattern>
            </servlet-mapping>

    </web-app>
```

Dispatcher servlet:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
            xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

            <context:component-scan base-package="com.in28minutes" />

            <mvc:annotation-driven />

        </beans>
```

Controller:

```
    package com.springweb.springmvc;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

    @Controller
    public class LoginController {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/login")
        @ResponseBody
        public String helloWorld() {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
```

pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.in28minutes</groupId>
    <artifactId>in28Minutes-first-webapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <path>/</path>
                        <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am using eclipse as my IDE. It says in the description:

> The requested resource is not available.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it but I do not unrderstand. Does it have to require the base-package="com.in28minutes" in dispatcher servlet to match the packages names?

Comment: Hello! Yes it should. When you add `<context:component-scan base-package="com.in28minutes" />` to dispatcher servlet xml, that mean, that spring searching annotated class in packages, that are root or child. If you add annotated class in other package, in you example: `com.springweb.springmvc`, spring doesn't find it.